# Can i load a dynamic library using JNI in a android native activity？

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native-activity

I am trying to create an application that uses Android Native Activity in order to avoid explosing my function code in java, but i meet a problem that i also want to use my another written dynamic library which uses JNI.
I want to know whether i can load such a dynamic library in native activity or not. It seems like that dlopen() can not perform well. Can i use reflection to call System.loadlibrary(), or indeed there exist some dramatic way to solve it?
Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

NativeActivity gives you all you need to use JNI. You should be able to load your library using dlopen:

```
dlopen("libname.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL)
```

Make sure to call JNI_OnLoad/JNI_OnUnload if your library has any. This will mimic what System.loadLibrary Java function does.

I have used JNI libraries and Java libraries from NativeActivity-based apps. So if you experience any particular problem with dlopen in this environment, feel free to open a separate question with more detail.